# Final ,Static ,Private Keywords

Tags: java, keyword

hi Sorry to Disturb you all.This may be asking from you'll several times by some one else.But i searched to find a correct answer for this type of question.But couldn't find.

What i want to know is what is the important of Final ,Static ,Private Keywords in Java. ?
and how they behave.

Thank You,
Have a nice Day !

Shaks

Answer (score 4):

Simplistically:

Final means it cannot be changed once you set it to something. In other words, this will not work:

```
final int xyzzy = 42;
xyzzy = 99;
```

A more concrete example is a named constant such as:

```
final int BOARDSIZE = 8; // chess-like game
```

Static means it belongs to the class rather than any single object (all objects share a single static member). Member variables usually have one copy per object. Changing a static member in one object will change it for *all* objects of that class.

An example may be a configuration item for all objects in the class, such as:

```
static boolean useMetric = true;
```

Private means that it can only be seen by the class itself, not by other classes. This aids encapsulation, a pivotal part of object oriented coding practice. I won't provide a specific example of this since it should be the case by default for most code. You expose the inner workings of your classes only as much as you absolutely have to, and no more.

Comment: U have any real life experience examples ?? Just to have a clear idea.Cos i'm new to java and a self learner..

Answer (score 1):

**Final**: This is just like a constant in the C  language. It doesn't allow changing the value of final variable.

1. It is used to prevent method overriding
2. It is used to prevent inheriting.
3. It doesn't allow changing the value.

**Static**: If the value is same for all we are using static keyword.

**Private**: The access permission of private is with  in the class.

final, static are modifiers / private is access modifier